# Way to create acidic/HCl gel?

Tags: acid-base, gel

Is there a way to turn azeotropic hydrochloric acid into a gel?

I am trying to remove barnacles from the bottom of a boat and normal hydrochloric acid works, but it is tedious because in liquid form it just runs off, so I have to keep applying it over and over, kind of wearing the barnacle away.

If I could turn the HCl into a gel then it could just be applied for a few minutes and remove the whole barnacle.

Comment: Just use proper (and standard) cleaning agents. I've never heard before that someone use conc. HCl for cleaning (and I heard of way more original methods).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out somebody already answered the question in a different post:

> Xanthan Gum can handle hydrochloric / muriatic acid (HCl) for a while,
>   depending on how concentrated the acid is. Here is how I made an HCl
>   gel to clean an old toilet that was heavily coated with lime scale...
>
> I first dissolved a level teaspoon of xanthan gum into 1/4 cup of
>   rapidly stirring water. After a few hours of letting it sit, with
>   occasional stirring, I had a very thick, viscous goo. To make the HCl
>   gel, I mixed one part of this goo with 1.5 parts of 31% hydrocholoric
>   acid, by volume. This gave a gel of a suitable viscosity to get the
>   lime dissolved off the toilet. I don't know how long this gel would
>   last before the HCl broke down the gum, but my gel lasted several
>   hours, which was enough to get the toilet clean.

Comment: If you are quoting another post it would be nice if you would include a link as reference.